# A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. memory leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-ndk, java-native-interface

If I comment out the method (*a)->CallVoidMethod(a, b, meth, "FROM JNI");
The app doesn't crash else it crashes.

Assuming that I haven't released the resource "jstr" which might have caused a memory leak then why does it happen only when CallVoidMethod() ?

What should I do to solve this issue?
Thanks to all who spend their time writing down a solution or reading through this

ERROR:

> android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>   java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called

This is my native "C" code ...

```
#include "com_example_prabhu_helloworldnative_HelloWorld.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "testjni"
#define  ALOG(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_prabhu_helloworldnative_HelloWorld_HelloJNI(JNIEnv *a, jobject b)
{
    //jstring jstr = (*a)->NewStringUTF(a, "This comes from jni....");
    jclass clazz =(*a)->GetObjectClass(a, b);
    jmethodID meth = (*a)->GetMethodID(a, b, "messageMe", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "\n this is log messge \n");
    ALOG("Hello World");
    if(meth == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    (*a)->CallVoidMethod(a, b, meth, "FROM JNI");
    //(*a)->Release
    ALOG("REACHING HERE");

    return (*a)->NewStringUTF(a, "APXOR");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StrictMode only reports failures to release objects that are explicitly monitored by StrictMode. It doesn't fire because you fail to release a string from JNI. The object allocated at the point in the code indicated by the stack trace needs to be released with an explicit `close()` call before the last reference to it is dropped. If the object is discarded and finalized before it is closed, the system reports an error.

The method you're calling may or may not have anything to do with the failing object -- it may simply be doing allocations that cause the GC to happen sooner, so your app reports the error immediately rather than doing so later.

Including more of the logcat output in your question may be useful here.  The strict mode code is typically configured to issue warnings... if your app is actually *crashing* the problem may not be related to the failure to close the resource.

One possible problem with your code is misuse of `b`.  You're passing it to `GetMethodID()`, which takes a `jclass` as its second argument; since that apparently works, I would expect 'b' to be a class.  This will be the case if the `HelloJNI` method were declared `static` in the Java code.  (You call `GetObjectClass(a,b)`, but ignore the result.)  That being the case, passing 'b' as the second argument to `CallVoidMethod()` is probably wrong, and will lead to a failure.

Further, as noted in another answer, you cannot pass a C string or `char*` when a `jstring` is required.  "FROM JNI" must be converted to a jstring with `NewStringUTF`.  The compiler should warn about that.

With CheckJNI enabled I would expect a JNI error to be reported, which does kill the app.

Comment: YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create Java string yourself:

```
...
jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("FROM JNI");
(*a)->CallVoidMethod(a, b, meth, str);
env->DeleteLocalRef(str);
...
```

Comment: Tried that it didn't work so I commented in the code